# Localization directly to xaml code on windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

How can I bind value from my resources files (es,en resources) to a element on page like text blocks and so on.

I've found [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965329(v=win.10).aspx) but in this case is using C#, I want to do it but just put some binding on the element markup not coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page clearly shows how to associate controls to resources:

> You need to associate every control that needs localized text with the
>   .resw file. You do this using the x:Uid attribute on your XAML
>   elements like this

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="Greeting" Text="" />
```

Have you tried it?

Comment: I miss understood the way that its works, but I can set properties on resources file per object. Thanks.